# dpkg / apt-get conflicting information

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

When I run `dpkg -l`, I get a list of installed packages, and I'm comparing that to a "model" system that I'm attempting to reproduce. There are several packages appearing in that list, for example `emacs23`, that I wish to remove. When I run `apt-get remove emacs23`, however, I'm told that the `emacs23` package isn't installed:

```
# apt-get -y remove emacs23
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package emacs23 is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 97 not upgraded.
```

Running `apt-get update` did not help:

Updated information:

```
# dpkg -l emacs23
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version        Description
+++-==============-==============-============================================
rc  emacs23        23.3+1-1ubuntu The GNU Emacs editor (with GTK+ user interfa

# apt-cache policy emacs23
emacs23:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 23.3+1-1ubuntu9.2
  Version table:
     23.3+1-1ubuntu9.2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     23.3+1-1ubuntu9.1 0
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
     23.3+1-1ubuntu9 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages

# dpkg -l | grep emacs23
rc  emacs23                          23.3+1-1ubuntu9.2                   The GNU Emacs editor (with GTK+ user interface)
```

How do I resolve this apparent confusion?

Comment: Please add the output of  `dpkg -l emacs23` to your question.

Comment: open terminal and run `apt-cache policy emacs23` add output to Q

Comment: `dpkg -l emacs23` and `apt-cache policy emacs23` output added.

Comment: `emacs23 ` not there...what is your exact Q....

Comment: `emacs23` shows up in `dpkg -l`. The system thinks it is there. How do I get ti to not show up in `dpkg -l` ?

Comment: have you see `emacs23` in `dpkg -l | grep emacs23`.....command

Comment: Yes. `emacs23` shows up when I run `dpkg -l` and when I grep for it in the output. That is the problem I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man dpkg`:

```
   -l, --list [package-name-pattern...]
          List  packages  matching given pattern. If no package-name-pattern is given, list all packages in /var/lib/dpkg/status, excluding the
          ones marked as not-installed (i.e. those which have been previously purged).
```

This means that `dpkg-l` lists all the *non-purged* packages, and **not** all the *installed* packages;

In fact, from `man dpkg-query` (to which `dpkg -l` acts as a front-end):

```
          Desired action:
            u = Unknown
            i = Install
            h = Hold
            r = Remove
            p = Purge

          Package status:
            n = Not-installed
            c = Config-files
            H = Half-installed
            U = Unpacked
            F = Half-configured
            W = Triggers-awaiting
            t = Triggers-pending
            i = Installed
```

Which means that `rc` at the start of the line means:

- `r`: The package's Desired action is: "Remove";
- `c`: The package's Status is: only configuration files are present;

Since you want to reproduce an existing system, packages with an `rc` Desisred action / Status combination that don't appear in the "model" system should be purged:

```
sudo apt-get purge emacs23
```

As a side-effect, those packages won't even pop up in `dpkg -l` anymore.

Comment: Is there a way to remove the config files and convince the system that `emacs23` was never installed in the first place?

Comment: @John Sure, if you purge the package it will be gone. `sudo apt-get purge emacs23`

Comment: @John Was that actually your question? Initially I read "There are several packages appearing in that list, for example `emacs23`, that I wish to remove" as "There are several packages appearing in that list, for example `emacs23`, that I wish to remove *from the output list*", but after your last question I'm pretty sure you actually meant "There are several packages appearing in that list, for example `emacs23`, that I wish to remove *from the system*".

Comment: My goal was "I want the system to think these packages were never installed." I come from the land of Fedora / RHEL, so I'm not completely used to the Debian / Ubuntu way of managing packages yet.

Comment: @John Ok now I got exactly what you wanted. Not that it adds something to what we said already here in the comments but I updated my answer to fit the question better anyway.